# how to bind a unique ID to a pre tag

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add an unique ID to all pre tags with jquery:

```
$('pre').each(function(){

          $(this).attr('id', $(this).uniqueId());

        });
```

This creates:

```
<pre class="CodeBlock linenums" id="[object Object]">
```

How can I achieve this so it works proper?

**Update:** to catch all the text between pre elements I made this wih php and js:

```
$SelectButton = '<span class="control-copytextarea" onclick="return fieldtoclipboard.copyfield(event, \\\'id1\\\')">[Select and Copy]</span><br />';
```

in combination with:

```
$('.Message .CodeBlock', this).wrap('<div class=surroundpre></div>');
    $('.surroundpre').prepend('$Uniquepreid');
```

The **id1** in the php string should also have the same unique ID as the pre elemnt below of it. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is the problem that the ID isn't the form you want, and/or that all tags get the same ID, and/or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the library https://api.jqueryui.com/uniqueId/
The function uniqueId(): Generate and apply a unique id for the set of matched elements.

Only with jQuery

Alternatively, only this library

```
$('div').each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('id') == undefined){
        $(this).attr('id','id'+Math.floor((Math.random() * 99999999) + 1))
    }
});
```

Comment: Try, $('pre').each(function(){
          $(this).uniqueId()
          //$(this).attr('id', $(this).uniqueId());

        });

Comment: Works great. One more question: see post above updated